# probability a negative drift random walk is positive after certain time

Tags: random-walks

Suppose I have a simple continuous time random walk starting at $0$ at time $0$ with Poisson transition rate 1 and probability $p$  the jump is $+1$ and probability $1-p$ thejump is $-1$. Suppose $p < 1/2$ so the drift is negative. I am interested in $q_t$, the probability that the random walk will be nonnegative at some time after t. Is there a nice closed form expression ?

Comment: The question is not the probability being nonnegative AT a particular time t but AT or AFTER a particular time t.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread.